# Can I create a virtual 3d model of a building from 2 dimensional blueprints on PDF?

Tags: pdf, 3d-modeling

I would like to create a 3d model of a building starting from the blue prints. I have tried extensively to draw a model of the building manually in sketchup from google, but I either lack the skills or it really is difficult.

Since I do have the scans of the blue prints as PDF, I am wondering if I could create a 3d-model of a building from its blue prints semi-automatically.  I have the floor plans, the lateral views, the front and the back views. So I would expect with some interpolation it should be possible. Am I right here, or should I get some proper 3d-modeling training.

Comment: If the blueprints are as an image (not in a vectorial format) embedded on to the .pdf, then you need to do almost everything by hand. Or some advanced OCR program could do it for you (pass the 2D to a say .dwg file), with flaws.

Comment: It isn't easy (or linear) to interpolate 2D data to 3D, mainly because of the amount of information present on the blueprint. You could import the 2D to a program like SketchPad or AutoCad and from there build up.

Answer (score 2):

This is not an easily automated task. Depending on what you want to do with this model or what your motivation for learning how to do it is, you might be better off just finding someone who has 3D modeling experience and asking them to model it for you. If there is a local college or university near you that has an architecture program you might be able to find a student to do this for you relatively inexpensively.

Sketchup is a pretty accessible program to start with if you want to do it yourself and end up with a model file, but it's pretty basic as far as architectural modeling tools go (which is good if you want to start learning how to model, but not so good if you want a robust model). Autodesk has a free online tool called [HomeStyler](http://www.homestyler.com) that might suit your needs, again depending on what you want to use the model for since it might not be possible to export a model, just work with it online.